# Generate meta tags for paging on views, refactoring needed for 'if else'

Tags: php, yii

I know this is a long code and hard to read but when i started working on this it was just a few if-s, and as time passed i added more and more and came to this. Tried refactoring it by my self and anything i tried to do had no effect on code. Switch statements don't work here( doesn't lower amount of lines needed for it to work, or i couldn't find a way for switch to work, which is more likely). If any one can help I would be grateful.

```
if (isset($request)) {
    $page = $request->get('page');
}
if ($pages->pageCount == 1 || $pages->pageCount == 0) {
    if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'category') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/category/' . $category], true)]);
} else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'index') {
    $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Yii::$app->urlManager->hostInfo . Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl . '/blog']);
} else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'archive') {
    $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $year . '/' . $month], true)]);
} else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'author') {
    if ($page != null) {
        $this->title = $user_name->username . ' - Travel blog | Page ' . $page . ' | Clickstay';
    } else {
        $this->title = $user_name->username . ' - Travel blog | Clickstay';
    }
    $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/author/' . $name], true)]);
} else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'search') {
    $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::current([], true)]);
}
}else {
if ($currentPage == 1) {
    if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'category') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/category/' . $category], true)]);
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'next', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/category/' . $category . '/' . $next], true)]);
    } else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'index') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Yii::$app->urlManager->hostInfo . Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl . '/blog']);
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'next', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $next], true)]);
    } else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'archive') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $year . '/' . $month], true)]);
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'next', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $next], true)]);
    } else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'author') {
        if ($page != null) {
            $this->title = $user_name->username . ' - Travel blog | Page ' . $page . ' | Clickstay';
        } else {
            $this->title = $user_name->username . ' - Travel blog | Clickstay';
        }
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/author/' . $name], true)]);
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'next', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/author/' . $name . '/' . $next], true)]);
    } else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'search') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::current([], true)]);
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'next', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/search/' . $next . '?q=' . $search . '/'], true)]);
    }
} else if ($currentPage > 1 && $currentPage != $pages->pageCount) {
    if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'category') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/category/' . $category . '/' . $currentPage], true)]);
        if ($page != 2) {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/category/' . $category . '/' . $prev], true)]);
        } else {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/category/' . $category], true)]);
        }
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'next', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/category/' . $category . '/' . $next], true)]);
    } else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'index') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $currentPage], true)]);
        if ($page != 2) {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $prev], true)]);
        } else {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/'], true)]);
        }
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'next', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $next], true)]);
    } else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'archive') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $currentPage], true)]);
        if ($page != 2) {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $prev], true)]);
        } else {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $year . '/' . $month], true)]);
        }
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'next', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $next], true)]);
    } else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'author') {
        if ($page != null) {
            $this->title = $user_name->username . ' - Travel blog | Page ' . $page . ' | Clickstay';
        } else {
            $this->title = $user_name->username . ' - Travel blog | Clickstay';
        }
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/author/' . $name . '/' . $currentPage], true)]);
        if ($page != 2) {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/author/' . $name . '/' . $prev], true)]);
        } else {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/author/' . $name], true)]);
        }
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'next', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/author/' . $name . '/' . $next], true)]);
    } else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'search') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::current([], true)]);
        if ($page != 2) {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/search/' . $prev . '?q=' . $search], true)]);
        } else {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/search/?q=' . $search], true)]);
        }
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'next', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/search/' . $next . '?q=' . $search], true)]);
    }
} else if ($currentPage == $pages->pageCount) {
    if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'category') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/category/' . $category . '/' . $currentPage], true)]);
        if ($page != 2) {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/category/' . $category . '/' . $prev], true)]);
        } else {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/category/' . $category], true)]);
        }
    } else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'index') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $currentPage], true)]);
        if ($page != 2) {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $prev], true)]);
        } else {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/'], true)]);
        }
    } else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'archive') {
        if ($page != null) {
            $this->title = $user_name . ' - Travel blog | Page ' . $page . ' | Clickstay';
        } else {
            $this->title = $user_name . ' - Travel blog | Clickstay';
        }
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $currentPage], true)]);
        if ($page != 2) {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $prev], true)]);
        } else {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/'], true)]);
        }
    } else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'author') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/author/' . $name . '/' . $currentPage], true)]);
        if ($page != 2) {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/author/' . $name . '/' . $prev], true)]);
        } else {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/author/' . $name], true)]);
        }
    } else if (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'search') {
        $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => Url::current([], true)]);
        if ($page != 2) {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/search/' .$prev. '?q=' . $search], true)]);
        } else {
            $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'prev', 'href' => Url::to(['blog/search' . '?q=' . $search], true)]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to solve this using polymorphism but it probably would get worse before it got better. There is an excellent site I just found with Martin Fowlers catalogue of refactorings: https://refactoring.guru

First I can see that you have 5 types of actions (category, index, archive, author, search). I would try to separate those actions to a single conditional, something like this:

```
$action = \Yii::$app->controller->action->id;

if($action == "category") {
    if ($pages->pageCount == 1 || $pages->pageCount == 0) {
        ...
    } else {
        if ($currentPage == 1) {
            ...
        } else if ($currentPage > 1 && $currentPage != $pages->pageCount) {
            ...
        } else if ($currentPage == $pages->pageCount) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

if($action == "index") {
    ...
```

I would do that for each of the actions. There will be more code for sure but it will still be a little bit more simple.

Next you could try to refactor it out to different classes, that might be a little bit cumbersome and you would probably have to pass in alot of variables to the class. This depends a little bit how far you want to take it and if you feel it is worth it.

You would want to have a parent class so you can pull up methods from your subclasses.
Personally I would probably use the factory pattern for creating the new objects and and introduce parameter object (https://refactoring.guru/introduce-parameter-object)

But ideally, your code in the end would probably look something like this:

```
$actionLink = ActionLinkFactory::create(\Yii::$app->controller->action->id);
$actionLink->setParameters(new ActionLinkParameters([
    "pageCount" => $pages->pageCount,
    "currentPage" => $currentPage,
    ...
]));

$actionLink->registerTag();
```

Ther is no silver bullet unfortunately, but you dont have to do everything at once either.

Comment: I was afraid u would say something like that... I'll try with that one